# Slight glitch in CSS animation

Tags: css, animation

There's a very small glitch in a CSS animation I've made for a responsive menu icon that turns into an "X" when clicked. The top line of the menu icon flickers down about 1px once the X shape has been made, so it is effectively still moving once the others have stopped. I've been messing around with it for hours but haven't been able to stop it happening – can anyone think of a way in which I could do this, or even a better way of achieving that animation?

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/58/

**HTML:**

```
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>

</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 21px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 21px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:#888;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
    transition: all .8s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n) {
    top: 2px;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+1) {
    top: 8px;
    opacity:1;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+2) {
    top: 14px;
}

.bar.open {
    background-color:#666;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n).open {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 23px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 7.5px;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+1).open {
    opacity:0;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+2).open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);  
    width: 23px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 7.5px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('.menu-button').click(function() {
        $('.bar').toggleClass('open');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bar:nth-child(3n+1)` top property and `.bar:nth-child(3n).open` and `.bar:nth-child(3n+2).open` top properties should be off same value;

**Example**

I replaced `top:7.5px` with `top:8px` at `.bar:nth-child(3n).open` and `.bar:nth-child(3n+2).open`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('.menu-button').click(function() {
        $('.bar').toggleClass('open');

    });

});
```

```css
.menu-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 21px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 21px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:#888;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
    transition: all .8s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n) {
    top: 2px;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+1) {
    top: 8px;
    opacity:1;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+2) {
    top: 14px;
}

.bar.open {
    background-color:#666;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n).open {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 23px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 8px; /* Changed this from 7.5px to 8px */
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+1).open {
    opacity:0;
}

.bar:nth-child(3n+2).open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);  
    width: 23px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 8px; /* Changed this from 7.5px to 8px */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <span class="menu-button">
  
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  
   </span>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I'm not sure why I'd made the numbers different.